# When debugging in Visual studio, can you see what is being returned from a method?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a method like:

```
object bibble()
{
  return GetFishsticks();
}
```

I step through the code until the return line, and press F10 to step to the next line... so the selected line is on the }

I'd like to see what's being returned, but I can't figure out how. Is there a way to see it?

Edit (by Doc Brown): this is bothering me, too, sometimes: is there a way to inspect the return value *without changing the code* and without calling `GetFishsticks` again, to avoid possible side effects?

Comment: I guess what you want to know is: is there a way to see the return value *without making changes to the code*.

Comment: I don't want to call the method myself in the immediate window etc. because it's likely that in many cases it will change something in the database or add a record etc. and I don't want multiples

Answer (score 4):

Do it like this...

```
object bibble()
{ 
    object fishSticks = GetFishsticks();
    return fishSticks;
}
```

Now you can put a breakpint on the return statement.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way without creating an extra object just for one line

Comment: @SLC: You aren't creating an extra object, you're only creating an extra variable.

Comment: @Adam Robinson: the question (which is bothering me, too), is: is there an easy way to inspect the return value without changing the code (and without calling the method twice which will happen if you put it in the Immediate or Watch window)?

Comment: @Doc, Oh, I get that, but I wanted the OP to be aware that he's not actually creating a "new" object (in case that was his objection to changing the code). FWIW, I *think* the VB debugger may provide this facility, but it's been awhile since I've used it.

Answer (score 2):

In C# it isn´t possible (as others already mentioned) without defining a variable to store the return value. But VB.NET provides such functionality due to VB6 legacy support. Take a look at this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2011/01/12/why-the-debugging-difference-between-c-and-vb-net-return-values.aspx).

Comment: IMHO this is the most useful answer here, because the blog entry explains why the C# debugger does not support it (yet!).

Answer (score 1):

You could step one line further (or step out) and see what the function that called bibble receives.

Comment: Unfortunately it rarely assigns it to a variable, often it is passing it to another method or doing something else with the result

Comment: @SLC then the only option is to assign it to a variable. that will make the code more readable too. BTW: how do you check for `null` if you do not assign it to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

SLC, you can copy the whole method call with its parameters inside the Watch window, I just did it while debugging and works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you've breaked right after the method call and it has no side-effects or mutable state that affects the outcome of multiple calls you could call it again in the immediate window? I.e. type "GetFishsticks()" in the immediate window. Just be aware that execution needs to be stopped in the same stack-frame as where you do the call.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the Immediate Window?

I know you can use the Immediate Window for get a value, but I don't know if it also works for method, but it would be easy find out.

Edited:
I just made a test, and it works fine.
Just write the `GetFishSticks()` in the Immediate Window, and press enter, and the result will be displayed below.

Comment: Yes, you can call methods from the immediate window.